# Why did the Harry Potter book novel series end?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did the Harry Potter **book series** end?

I get why the movies would have to end; because the actors were no longer kids and it's better to have a conclusion than end halfway through, due to actors wanting to move on, which I would understand anyway. But why did J. K. Rowling get rid of such good characters like Harry, Ron and Hermione if she continued on the the world she'd created in Fantastic Beasts and other add-ons. Couldn't she have continued writing about Harry, Ron and Hermione or maybe some other students at Hogwarts?

Comment: This is mostly on topic, so long as you cut out the call for opinions, which is firmly off topic .  I'm sure someone can dig up a reason about why JKR chose to only focus the main story on the high school years.

Comment: Series centered on Harry; Harry had to be growing up; when he turned 17 the protection his mother gave him would expire; when that happened Voldie had to attack; there had to be a showdown between them; only one could survive. The series couldn't realistically be extended further.

Comment: Yes. It's like the difference between Lord of the Rings (epic story ending in final confrontation) and Superman (open-ended series of adventures with recurring villains). One is not necessarily better than the other, but they are different styles of storytelling, and JKR very deliberately chose the first one.

Answer (score 16):

It is just the way Rowling always planned it (for the main series at least)

> Richard: I was dodging around the death bit, because I know you can't answer that question, But you know how Conan-Doyle got sick up to there of Sherlock Holmes ...
>
> Jo: Yeah.
>
> Richard: ... so pushed him off the cliff at the Reichenbech falls, I'm not asking if you have done that obviously, but have you ever been tempted to bump him off because it is such a huge thing in your life.
>
> Jo: I've never been tempted to kill him off before the end of book 7. **I have always planned seven books and that is where I want to go, where I want to finish on seven books.** But I can completely understand the mentality of an author who thinks "Well I am going to kill them off because that means there can be no non-author written sequels as they call them, so it will end with me and after I am dead and gone" - they would be able to bring back the character and write a load of ...

She also planned the ending from the very beginning:

> Jo: No, the last book is not finished, though I am well into it now.
>
> Richard: But you have written the finale already?
>
> Jo: I wrote the final chapter in something like 1990? - oh hang on - **I wrote the final chapter in something like 1990.**
>
> [26 June 2006 - *Richard and Judy Show*, Channel Four Corporation (UK)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0626-ch4-richardandjudy.html)

In the end you also have to consider her target audience was children and young adults. The books did "grow" with the reader as each installment became a bit more mature. However, even Rowling being such a great planner it is very difficult to plan an indefinite story. The story has grown over the years with the *Cursed Child*, *Fantastic Beasts* series, and numerous other short writings on Pottermore. You have to account for what the creator wants to do, go where they want the story to go...

Answer (score 0):

The Harry Potter series was solely about Harry's time at Hogwarts, which has seven years. Following his story outside of Hogwarts and into adulthood would be quite pointless. Obviously, as Harry Potter fans we would have been happy with 37 books (a book for each year Harry has been alive) but again, it would be pointless and of no use to the actual story which is of Harry Potter defeating Voldemort and saving the wizarding world.

We have *Cursed Child*, *Fantastic Beasts* and loads of other Harry Potter articles, stories, etc, so it's not as if it's ended for good. But, yes, the Harry Potter series had to end. It was inevitable.